# Вывод изображения в новом окне

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, изображения, tkinter-canvas

Подскажите, что нужно дописать? 
Есть окно с кнопкой, при нажатии на которую появляется новое окно.

Как сделать чтобы в новом окне фоном было изображение в `Canvas`?

```
import random
import imghdr
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def yes():
    new_window_1 = Toplevel(root)
    new_window_1.title("Teljesen igaza van!")
    new_window_1.resizable(0, 0)
    new_window_1.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    canvas_1 = Canvas(new_window_1, width=400, height=400, bg="yellow", highlightthickness=0)
    canvas_1.pack()

def motionMouse(event):
    btnNo.place(x=random.randint(0, 500), y=random.randint(0, 500))
    

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
root.title('Felmérés')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root['bg'] = 'white'

label = Label(root, text='Tamás buzi?', font='Arial 20 bold', bg='white').pack()
btnYes = Button(root, text='Igen', font='Arial 20 bold', command=yes).place(x=170, y=100)

btnNo = Button(root, text='Nem', font='Arial 20 bold')
btnNo.place(x=350, y=100)
btnNo.bind('<Enter>', motionMouse)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import random
import imghdr
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


tkimage = None                                                       # <----

def yes():
    global tkimage                                                   # <----
    
    new_window_1 = Toplevel(root)
    new_window_1.title("Teljesen igaza van!")
    new_window_1.resizable(0, 0)
    new_window_1.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    canvas_1 = Canvas(new_window_1, width=400, height=400, 
        bg="yellow", highlightthickness=0)
    canvas_1.pack()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    filename = 'lena2.png'
    image = Image.open(filename)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas_obj = canvas_1.create_image(
        0, 0, 
        image=tkimage,
        anchor="nw")
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

def motionMouse(event):
    btnNo.place(x=random.randint(0, 500), y=random.randint(0, 500))


root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')
root.title('Felmérés')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root['bg'] = 'white'

label = Label(root, text='Tamás buzi?', font='Arial 20 bold', 
    bg='white').pack()
btnYes = Button(root, text='Igen', font='Arial 20 bold', 
    command=yes).place(x=170, y=100)

btnNo = Button(root, text='Nem', font='Arial 20 bold')
btnNo.place(x=350, y=100)
btnNo.bind('<Enter>', motionMouse)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]